# Check error status when RESTClient object failed creation?

Tags: rest, api, spock

```
def client = new RESTClient("http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/v1/")
def "create account"() {
    when: "contentType is not specified"
    def resp = client.post(
            path: 'accounts/add',
            body: [
                name: "First Account",
                externalID: 300202302,
                active: true
            ]
            )

    then: "should throw an error"
    thrown(NullPointerException)
    resp.status == 415
}
```

The problem is NullPointerException. When I try this on postman, it will return the error status of 415. I want to test this error status on spock.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to have the NPE, or can't you test the response due to the NPE?

Comment: i can't test the response due to NPE of RESTClient instance which contains the status 415 i want to test.

Comment: then you should fix the cause for the NPE. And a NPE does not contain any response status.

Comment: i just realized that my question should be what object to use for testing in spock instead of RESTClient, because I can get the error status 415 in postman

Comment: You want to know which library to use for REST testing in java/groovy? https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured comes to mind